# Getting sharepoint list items using knockout with rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I used the below code to get list items but it is going to error function and showing error in alert.

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function insightViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.insights = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.GetInsights = function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://demo/sites/Dev/_api/lists/getbytitle('CountryNames')/items",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    alert("Get data-"+data.d.results);
                   self.insights.push(data.d.results);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }

            });
        }
        self. GetInsights();
    }
        $(document).ready(function () {
         insightModel = new insightViewModel();
        var insightDiv = document.getElementById("divDatabinding");
            insightViewModel();
        });
    //


</script>
<body>
<div id="divDatabinding"> 
    <table >
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Name</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody data-bind="foreach:insights">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="white-space: nowrap">
                                            <span class="spanlink" data-bind="click: function () { $root.RulesopenEditPanel($data) }">
                                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-up"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="white-space: pre-wrap" data-bind="text: Title"></td>

                                            <span class="spanlink" data-bind="click: function () { $root.RulesdeleteRecord($data) }">
                                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting this error...

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting, please try to be as detailed as possible in your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your REST-url is wrong, you are missing `/web`.

It should be

```
http://demo/sites/Dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('CountryNames')/items
```

Comment: wow - that's a quick edit @Robert Lindgren - you beat me to it!

Comment: Doing some server side code, so recycle time = edit time ;)

Comment: after using web also it is showing same error

Comment: What do you get if you access the URL in the browser?